# org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

Tags: android

I have a WebService in NetBeans using Oracle Database and when I do a select in Android I have this exception

```
org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive
```

Here is the code of the WebService:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "mostarNombre")
public String mostarNombre(@WebParam(name = "id") int id) {
    String nomb = "";
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:xxxx:xx", "SYSTEM", "xxxx");

        PreparedStatement consultaEmp = cn.prepareStatement("select nombre from ejemplo where id=?");
        consultaEmp.setInt(1, id);

        ResultSet rs = consultaEmp.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            nomb = rs.getString("nombre");
        } else {
            nomb = "No encontrado";
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return nomb;
}
```

And here the code from the Android Studio:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        String resultadoFINAL;
        //Creacion de la Solicitud
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD2);
        //Creacion del Envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //Creacion del transporte
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        String texto = this.etId.getText().toString();

        // Paso de parámetro
        PropertyInfo numeroEmp = new PropertyInfo();
        numeroEmp.setName("numero");
        numeroEmp.setValue(texto);
        numeroEmp.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(numeroEmp);

        //Llamada
        transporte.call(SOAPACTION2, sobre);

        //Resultado
        SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) sobre.getResponse();
        resultadoFINAL = "Nombre: "+resultado.toString();
        tvConsulta.setText(resultadoFINAL);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exception is in this line:

```
SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) sobre.getResponse();
```

I'm new with WebService, so I appreciate all the help !!! :)

**EDIT:**

I tried with:

```
SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) sobre.getResponse();
```

This:

```
SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) sobre.getResponse();
resultadoFINAL = "Nombre: "+resultado.getProperty(0).toString();
```

And with this:

```
Object resultado = (Object) sobre.getResponse();
```

With Object I get "No encontrado", It's like in this loop the ResultSet doesn't have next():

```
if (rs.next()) {
     nomb = rs.getString("nombre");
} else {
     nomb = "No encontrado";
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. You should really avoid using that Thread Policy thing. It's an anti pattern in Android development

Comment: Also, if you're new to web services, I'll point out that JSON over HTTP is more popular than SOAP

Comment: What you recommend me ?

Comment: NetBeans doesn't really matter. You can use any other WebService in any other IDE. Oracle recently released their own called Helidon, most people use Spring Framework or Vert.x, but lately I've been using DropWizard

Comment: I edited the question, I hope that's help you

Comment: Where are you using `ResultSet`? That is a completely separate issue than the initial question

Comment: It´s the same problem, I'm using ResultSet in the WebService method `@WebMethod(operationName = "mostarNombre")`

Comment: I have the same exception, but with `Object resultado = (Object) sobre.getResponse();` I don't get the exception, but I have the problem with ResultSet

Comment: I feel like you should create a new post and accept the below answer, which resolved the first exception you had.

Answer (score 1):

it should possibly rather be:

```
SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) sobre.getResponse();
```

... in order to avoid that impossible cast exception.

Comment: With this i don't get exception but I get anyType{} in resultado.ToString()

Comment: @Beardman impossible to tell why/how without having seen the associated WSDL or plain text response. `anyType{}` without any content hints for an empty response envelope.

Comment: What I should append to my question ?

Comment: the `@Serializable` class & raw response envelope would possibly help to tell more... there are countless similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SoapObject

Comment: Sorry, I checked again and with this I get the exception too

Comment: this claim completely contradicts the error message ...because there only is `SoapObject` and `SoapPrimitive`. unless you add the raw response or the WSDL, it's impossible to tell what's wrong - because with SOAP serialized `SoapObject` or simple `SoapPrimitive` are being exchanged. possibly even the `SOAPAction` of the `soap:Envelope` you use to request is wrong already - which may subsequently lead to an unexpected (or empty) response. the basic idea is to make the `SoapObject` a Java `Object`, without messing around much.